# How to redirect to another page using a session according to the query string?

Tags: php

What I'm after is the ability to append ?key=1234 to my page url and
it will show the page fine. Not having the key appended would redirect
to elsewhere, hoping someone could help.
What I have so far is below but I cannot make out why it does not work.
'

```
session_start();

$self = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}";

if(!empty($_GET['key']) &&  $_GET['key'] == "1234" )  {
    unset($_GET['key']);
    $qs = http_build_query($_GET);
    $self = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?{$qs}";
    $_SESSION['key'] = 1;
    header("Location: $self");
    exit;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
    header('Location: https://elsewhere.com');
    exit;
}

session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
include("mywebpage.php");
```

At the moment I'm alway being redirected elsewhere.com even with the correct key.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works, but you must not unset nor destroy session, you need it for the next page load! So, you can remove session_unset() and session_write_close(), even session_write_close(), that is not necessary in such script.

Comment: I don't get it, it works for you?! I just tried it with the modifications, I input domain.com/test1.php?key=1234 and still get sent to elsewhere.com? Either i'm doing something wrong or could it be my server? Forgive me not a coder.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Maybe you are still being redirected due to a server or navigator cache? To check this, just do die('ok'); before session_start(); If you are redirected again, then there is some kind of cache.